# What is this tall, bright orange, variety of Zinnia?

Tags: identification, zinnia

Bought a couple 6 packs of these Zinnias and don't recall the variety. I checked back at the garden store where I got them the next year and they didn't recall the variety and didn't have anything that looked like them that season.

They matched our fall sugar maple perfectly and I'd like to get them again.

My best guess is [Inca Orange Cactus](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=inca%20orange%20cactus%20zinnia&qpvt=Inca%20Orange%20Cactus%20zinnia&qpvt=Inca%20Orange%20Cactus%20zinnia&qpvt=Inca%20Orange%20Cactus%20zinnia&FORM=IGRE) type. They were 2-3+ foot tall.

[image: close up]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of looking I came up with an angustifolia hybrid that is fairly popular called 'Profusion Fire'....planted in big sweeps or masses are spectacular.  You should know that that color is prolific in Zinnias and I wouldn't worry about getting just the one variety.  And it looks to me that possibly we are looking at two different zinnias in your photos.  Or perhaps three, same color different variety.  Gorgeous flower.  I'd get Crocosmia the orangey red or the orangey yellow to plant in masses to harmonize with these Zinnias.  They are offset in flowering but would keep that color combo going with a bit different texture, same height.  Dark purple flowered plants and grey leaved perennials would totally make these colors powerful.  Senecio greyii.  No dusty miller please.  Ugh grey color.